# how to split panes (vertically and horizontally) straight from nerdree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

This question is a follow up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943802/macvimnerdtree-how-to-open-a-file-as-a-split-in-furthest-horizontal-split) (graphs copied from there). The OP was wondering how to split the pane of File 3 horizontally.

```
/========================================================\
|          |                      |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |     file 1           |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |______________________|                      |
| NERDTree |                      |     File 3           |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |    file 2            |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
\__________|______________________|______________________/
```

currently if I were to be on the `File 3` pane, then click on `ctrl+n` to jump to nerdtree, then select `<file name> + i`, my expectation is to have this:

```
/========================================================\
|          |                      |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |     file 1           |       File 4         |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |______________________|______________________|
| NERDTree |                      |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |    file 2            |      File 3          |
|          |                      |                      |
\__________|______________________|______________________/
```

but instead i am getting this:

```
/========================================================\
|          |                      |                      |
|          |       file 1         |                      |
|          |______________________|                      |                      
|          |                      |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
|          |       File 2         |        file 3        | 
| NERDTree |                      |                      |
|          |______________________|                      |                      
|          |                      |                      |
|          |       file 4         |                      |
|          |                      |                      |
\__________|______________________|______________________/
```

The OP found the solution by using a mouse with mvim. I would like a solution *without using a mouse* since the one of the main reasons I use vim is *not* to use a mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked question asks how to jump directly from *File 3* window to *NERDTree* window without hopping through *File 1* or *File 2* window first. The OP's solution is to use the mouse to click on the *NERDTree* window. If you're just asking for a non-mouse way to do that then one answer is `2^wh`. That is, hit <kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> then <kbd>H</kbd>. (Refer to `:h CTRL-W_CTRL-H`)

However, I don't think that'll solve your problem. But this does, based on my testing: `:set splitright`. Setting this causes new vertical splits to open to the right rather than the left (the default). With this I can recreate your four windows with *File 4* appearing in the same column as *File 3* when I open it from *NERDTree* with `s`.

**Update:** At first I thought the precise layout of three-windows didn't matter but if you have to have it look like your first diagram then you'll need to use another approach: from *File 3* window do `:split` then do the `2^wh` command to go to *NERDTree* and, lastly, choose a file with `o`. You'll end up in the same four-window layout that you asked for and the cursor will be in the newly opened fourth window.

You could even add a mapping that will take care of the split and cursor move with a key press or two.:

```
:nnoremap <leader>n :split \| :2winc h<CR>
```

In Normal mode enter `\n`. Or change that to some other unused key combo.

**Update 2:** An upvote drew my eye to this answer of mine and it occurred to me that it would be more convenient if you could use one mapping to go from *NERDTree* and the first layout shown in the question to *File 4* window of the second layout.

```
nnoremap <leader>o :2winc l \| split \| 2winc h \| norm o<CR>
```

Put the cursor on the file you want to open and instead of just hitting <kbd>O</kbd> (i.e. enter a lower case `o`) hit the leader key first then <kbd>O</kbd>. That's it. (There's nothing new as far as technique here, I'm just packaging things in a nicer way and saving someone from having to figure out the mapping.)

Comment: what is the reference for the `2` `Ctrl`  `+`  `W` `h`  part? I tried it once and it worked, but i couldn't make it work again. this is the sequence: press on `2` and `control` (at the same time) then release the keys then press on `shift` + `w` + `h`. that doesn't work though

Comment: See my updated answer. It's conventional to use capital letters with <kbd> because that's what we have on our keyboards, not lower-case (though I had a typo with "h"...it's now <kbd>H</kbd>). If I wanted to denote a capital letter then you'd see <kbd>Shift</kbd> before it. The other notation, though, uses lower-case.

Comment: you said _Refer to :h CTRL-W_CTRL-H_.. which reference are you talking about? i saw the help of nerd tree.. never found anything talking about that

Comment: i tried `set splitright`.. but same thing happened. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/VrUZ2NO.png)

Comment: _ With this I can recreate your four windows with File 4 appearing in the same column as File 3 when I open it from NERDTree with s_ .. maybe if you explain to me the sequence of steps you do right from the beginning.. maybe i'm starting differently than you that's why i'm ending up with different results

Comment: See my update. I didn't know you cared about having that exact three-window layout....thought it was just an interim state that wasn't important. Update has an approach that will work with that layout (though it doesn't use `s`...it uses `:split` + `o`).

Comment: Heh, thanks. I guess that means the solution works to your satisfaction, then. :)

Comment: yeap, here is a (kinda) related question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/shortcut-to-open-definition-of-variable-in-a-vertical-split