# shortcut to open definition of variable in a vertical split

Tags: split, key-bindings

I use the vertical split command a lot `:vsplit`, and I also have click on <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to look at the definition of a variable (after generating the Ctags).

I would like to do a keyboard shortcut that does both like so:
I see a variable I would like to see the definition of, so I put the cursor ontop of that variable, perform the keyboard shortcut, and then a vertical split on the right side should show with the definition of that variable (even if it's defined in the same file).. then I perform *another* keyboard shortcut to dismiss that new window and return to exactly where I was

How do I do that?

Comment: There is `CTRL-W CTRL-]` already to open the definition in a split. However, this opens a horizontal split, so it is not exactly what you want.

Comment: what does `CTRL-W` really mean? where can i find a documentation for it? I see it used everywhere

Comment: @abbood To know what `CTRL-W` means, you can try [`:h CTRL-W`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#CTRL-W) ;) It is the first part of the Window commands which allow to split, move, change the size (etc) of the windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the command line this will open a new vertical split with the tag target:

```
:vert winc ]
```

`:winc ]` is the command line equivalent of the `CTRL-W CTRL-]` key combo mentioned in [a comment above](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/21/karl-yngve-lerv%c3%a5g)...except neither the Normal mode version nor the command line version require the second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. `CTRL-W ]` is sufficient.

(In fact, many of the `CTRL-W` commands have variations where the second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is optional. The idea is to be forgiving if the user is rapidly pressing the keys and doesn't release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> quickly enough after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.)

Then we have the modifier `:vert` that for certain commands that open a horizontal split opens a vertical split instead. That's why we're using the command line for this rather than the Normal mode keys.

Anyways, sounds like you want a Normal mode mapping for it so

```
:nnoremap XX :vert winc ]<CR>
```

Change `XX` to whatever unused key combo you prefer.

To close the window and return to where you were press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: @abbood Did this work for you?

Comment: worked perfect @B Layer.. how can i have two different shortcuts one for vertical split on jump to definiton and another horizontal one?

Comment: You mean the same mapping as above except with a horizontal split? Just leave off `vert`. As it says, `vert` is a modifier that alters a command _that normally opens a horizontal split_.