# Shortcut to open definition of variable in a vertical split with Neovim mapping

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, lsp

This is a follow up question to [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/shortcut-to-open-definition-of-variable-in-a-vertical-split/14821#14821) where I would jump to the definition of a variable in a vertical split for ctags. I’m currently using an lsp language server like so:

```
  local bufopts = { noremap=true, silent=true, buffer=bufnr }
  local servers = { 'tsserver', 'eslint', 'bashls','jsonls' } 
  for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
      lspconfig[lsp].setup {
          ..
          on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
          end
      }
  end
```

How can I set up the keymap so that I can jump to the definition in a vertical split here?

### update

What I’m really asking here is how to combine vim commands with this `vim.lsp.buf.definition`

so by going over the [docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#lua-keymap) and trying to implement one of the [answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42124/14510), I did this

```
on_attach = function(client, bufnr)        
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gv', function() 
    vsplit vim.lsp.buf.definition
  end , bufopts)
```

but that didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
vsplit
lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()
```

It would look like this in init.lua

```lua
on_attach = function(client, bufnr)        
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gv', function() 
    vim.cmd([[
vsplit
]])
    vim.lsp.buf.definition()
  end, bufopts)
```

Comment: I’m not sure how to put that in the lua vim key mapping, please see update to question

Comment: I have updated my answer to translate it into lua.

Comment: I got this error now

```Cannot open file "buf.definition()"
E5108: Error executing lua: [string ":lua"]:139: Vim(vimgrep):E480: No match: lsp
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'cmd'
```

Comment: Sorry I can test yet myself and I make mistakes :-/ I have corrected the solution. It should be better :-|

Comment: nice it worked! bonus question: how can i do it so that the definition shows up in a pop-up window instead of a split window?  (already awarded +1 + correct answer lol)

Comment: It is more complex because you don't only need the location provided by the LSP server but also the definition range (where it start and where it end) I don't a plugin that does that but it could exist. I'll have a look :-)

Comment: Nice! Well I have a place to start from: https://github.com/MunifTanjim/nui.nvim, this guy is used in https://github.com/SmiteshP/nvim-navbuddy which I use relgiously :)

Comment: I’m trying to do it, you can see where i’m stuck [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/how-to-load-method-definition-in-a-popup)