# goto definition

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp

I'd like to have a shortcut ('gD', say) to go to the definition using `vim.lsp.buf.definition`; however, in a new tab (if this is not open yet), or in the tab already open.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/42123/10604) answer your question? (Probably change `:vsplit` for `:tabedit`?)